# Response Connection header has value 'close' even if keepAliveTimeout is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I have set keepAliveTimeout to 61000 for my express server using following code snippet.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8080);
server.keepAliveTimeout = 61 * 1000;
```

Still the connection header has value 'close' in response of my xhr request to this express server. What is the issue ? How can I update the response connection header to keep-alive.